# Can I implement smooth scrolling like in Chromium Smooth Scroller into an html page?

Tags: javascript, html, web

How could I use some javascript to integret the features found in Chromium Smooth Scroller into a webpage. Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this [smooth scroll plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

In configuration options,there are  parameters like `scrollinertia,scroll speed,and scroll amount`